# LayoutAnimationController not working when hiding View Group but works when Showing view group

Tags: android, animation, layout-animation

LayoutAnimationController is used to animate children of view group

I used **LayoutAnimationController** to show elements in **LinearLayout** with animation effect one by one using following code.

```
     Animation fadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.anim_fade_in);
//lnrContactContainer is LinearLayout.
            AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);
            set.addAnimation(fadeIn);
            set.setDuration(500);
            controller = new LayoutAnimationController(set, 1f);
            lnrContactContainer.setLayoutAnimation(controller);          
            lnrContactContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

But same approach does not work when I use it to show fadeout animation while hiding **LinearLayout** `lnrContactContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE)`;

Instead of hiding children one by one it hides the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Instead of hiding children one by one it hides the parent.

To hide the parent only after the `Animation` has been applied to all children, use an `AnimationListener`:

```
lnrContactContainer.setLayoutAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation){}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
            {
                lnrContactContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE)
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation){}
        });
```

By the way, my fadeout animation needed

```
set.setFillAfter(true);
```

to keep the items from popping in again after fading although my animation xml file (in res/anim) already contained `android:fillAfter="true"`.

Comment: `set.setFillAfter(true); ` thanks for directing me to this , I had this issue of children popping in again.

Comment: Just one question,
 why I have to start animation manually using `lnrContactContainer.startLayoutAnimation();` in case of hiding the `ViewGroup` but not in case of showing it ?

Comment: @Null n Void - in my test app, I triggered both types of animation by clicking on buttons. Both times, "lnrContactContainer.setLayoutAnimation(controller);" was called and the animation started right afterwards. OK, the difference is that I tested with a ListView not with a LinearLayout. So I don't know why, but there are some other differences between AdapterViews and "real" layouts .